# Subtract two quantities and split into fractional values

Tags: javascript, math, fractions

I'm having trouble coming up with a function for this sort of weird math operation I'm trying to accomplish. Say you have two quantities of a liquid in ounces. The two quantities can be broken up into only four different parts: 1oz, 32nds of 1oz, 64ths of 1oz, and 128ths of 1oz. For example theses two quantities could be:

| OZ | 32 | 64 | 128 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 22 | - | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | - | 1 |

I need to calculate the difference between these two quantities. This is easy to do by hand, but not so much programmatically. The expected result for this situation would be 1oz, 12/32, 0/64 and 2/128. I must end up with the quantities broken up into their smallest proponents, so 32/32 should roll over to be 1oz, etc. What is the best way to implement this?

Here’s what I’ve been attempting most recently (just converting to and from decimal):

1. Convert the quantity to fraction (like time to decimal)
   oz + (b * (1/32)) + (c * (1/64)) + (d * (1/128)) = 2.7109375
2. Take the whole number from the decimal: 2 = 2oz
3. Calculate 32nds from the remaining decimal (0.7109375 * (64/1) = 22 32nds with a remainder of 0.75
4. Try to calculate 64ths (should be zero), 0.75 * (64/1) = 48, which is incorrect.

This math is based on https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php

Comment: You could write two functions. One would convert the 4 numbers to one decimal represented number. And the other would do the reverse.  You convert all values to decimal, do the summation, and convert the result back. E.g. if you would be working with hours, minutes and seconds, you could calculate `decimal_hour = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600` and stuff like `seconds = trunc(decimal_hour*3600) % 60`, ...

Comment: @JohanC I think I understand what your saying, is there any way you can provide an example that is in the same terms of my question?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69861899/edit) your question and add your best-effort attempt?

Comment: @JohanC Okay, just added.

Comment: @JohanC No ideas?

Comment: Step 4: *Try to calculate 64ths (should be one), `0.75 * (1/32) * (64/1) = 1.5`, which is correct.* Note that 3/128 would normally be written as 1/64+1/128